# PHP MySQL with two query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to do a `SELECT * FROM table_X` , the problem is table_X is the result of another query, I don't know how to do it, perhaps with two loop, something like this :

```
<?php

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_ref");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{

     $name = $row['table_name'];

     $query2 = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM '$name' ");

     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) 
     {
         $time = $data['itime'];
         echo $time;      
     }
}

?>
```

The tables are all similar & I can't do joint there's no keys. So what I want is to show only the results of the second query from each results of the first query !

Comment: Sounds like you really need to overhaul your DB structure... How is the schema? Can you put together an sqlFiddle?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: This is wrong $time = $data['itime']; where do you get $data variable from?

Comment: What info from first query you need to bring the second query result?

Comment: Have you tried the above code? It's pretty close, you just need to sort your variable naming out (you invented a variable `$data`). But the need to do this at all is a sign of a badly designed database schema, you need to look at this and try and rearrenge the database so you *can* do a `JOIN` to get the results you need.

Comment: please post your table schema. `*` doesn't tell us much.

Comment: I need to extract from table_ref the names of the tables that i will next use to extract info from , the database is 10 Go and it's increasing every seconde , I don't how I can rearrange the structure

Comment: I have 67 tables, the last table name is 'table_ref' with (tbl_name,itime_start,itime_end,space_used) and in the others they have the same structure (id, itime, dtime, ip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what's your structure? I don't understand. You have column table_name where are listed a lot of tables? If so, just use backquotes on your $name:

```
$query2 = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM `$name` ");
```

Comment: I have a table (table_ref) where are listed all the names of the other tables. And i need to extract information from tables that only for exemple started yesterday (the database is increasing each minute)

Comment: You have table (table_ref) with what? A column where all tables are listed, or new column is created for each table?

Comment: a column where all tables are listed

Comment: Use it the way mentioned above. With backquotes. Also look at the answers below. You have some other mistakes like overwriting the $row and using undefined $data

Comment: ok i corrected all the error, instead of using mysql_query I used : $query2 = $bdd->query("SELECT itime FROM `".$name."` "); the only error i get is : Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in

Comment: Paste the new code. And in what line your error is. Edit your question adding the new code

Comment: $query1 = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM table_ref")or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo())); while ($row = $query1->fetch()) { ?> <?php $name = $row['tbl_name']; $query2 = $bdd->query("SELECT itime FROM ".$name." "); while ($row2 = $query2->fetch()) { $time= $query2['itime']; echo $time; } } error at : $time=$query2['itime'];

Comment: use `$row['itime']` instead of `$query2['itime']`

Comment: yeah it works ! but at the end i have the error :  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)

Comment: maybe get_object_vars() will help you to extract what you really need. Look at the documentation here http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php. You can have for example $array = array(); $array = get_object_vars($row); But if I were you, I would continue using objects.

Comment: Recieving that error, might means, that you have an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

just change your quotes to have the query ready to be started

**change**

```
 $query2 = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM '$name' ");
```

**to**

```
 $query2 = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM `".$name."` ");
```

i would also rather sugest to check this part

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) 
 {
     $time = $data['itime'];
     echo $time;      
 }
```

you already used variable `$row` to fetching previus query so better to change to something else, look like `$data` is matching your needs because you already used but you did not declare it

```
 while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) 
 {
     $time = $data['itime'];
     echo $time;      
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the obvious that has been pointed out in the comments, you're overwriting `$row` in the second loop.

Also, you're trying to read an array (`$data`) that is not defined.

The following will work much better (but still isn't ideal):

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT `table_name` FROM `table_ref`");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
     $name = $row['table_name'];
     $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT `itime` FROM `$name`");

     while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) 
     {
         $time = $data['itime'];
         echo $time;      
     }
}
```

Comment: I used this code :  


            $query1 = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM table_ref")or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
   
   while ($row = $query1->fetch())
   
   {  
  ?>
  
  <?php    
    
   
   $name = $row['tbl_name'];
   
   
   $query2 = $bdd->query("SELECT itime FROM `".$name."` ");
    
    while ($row2 = $query2->fetch())
     {
     
      $time= $query2['itime'];
      echo $time;
     }
             } 
the only error i get is :  Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in

Comment: Because `fetch()` returns a `PDOStatement` object, not an array. Read the manual > http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: what can i use instead of fetch then to obtain array

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

select x.* from ( SELECT table_name FROM table_ref) as x

Comment: what do i put in the first x then ? isn't table_name i should put there ?

Comment: what ever the alias u have declared just put it there